# How Can I deploy Laravel 5.8 + Vue application to shared hosting cpanel main domain and subdmains

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have already developed 2 applications and I want to deploy my first application which contains Vue Cli and Laravel Php framework on the main domain and the other application similarly made with Vue and Laravel in my subdomain. Please, could you suggest to me how could I perform these actions? Thanks

Comment: Try laravel forge!

Comment: I don't get your actual problem. Read this (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment) about laravel deployment.